# Remove duplicate NULL from Group by cube

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

If all the values are null in a GROUP BY cube, rollup or grouping set query, the result set contains one row for the value set to null and one for the value being null.

What is the best way to avoid or remove those duplicates?

Example:

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT x, null::BOOLEAN y FROM generate_series(1, 5) x
)
SELECT
  x,y
FROM v
GROUP BY cube (x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was answered in IRC by RhodiumToad:

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT x, null::BOOLEAN y FROM generate_series(1, 5) x
)
SELECT
  x,y, grouping(x,y)
FROM v
GROUP BY cube (x, y);
```